# Entity Framework Migrations: PrimaryKey

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a POCO model for which the Primary Key property maps onto a column with a different name.

The model is something like:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    //....more props
}
```

So the migration looks something like:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.dtlTransactions",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true, name: "intTransactionID"),
            //...more cols
        })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

When running the migration, however, I get:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Column name 'Id' does
>   not exist in the target table or view.

it seems as if the name property of the columnbuilder isn't utilised when generating sql. The -verbose option on the migration gives me this sql:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dtlTransactions] (
[intTransactionID] [bigint] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
--...other cols
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.dtlTransactions] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
```

Any ideas? Is this an obvious bug?

Comment: FWIW, the same bug seems to exist for ForeignKey and Index on TableBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

In order to tell Entity Framework the column name for the SQL queries that EF will generate you must specify it for the model, not in the Migration, either with data annotations...

```
[Column("intTransactionID")]
public long Id { get; set; }
```

...or with Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>()
    .Property(t => t.Id)
    .HasColumnName("intTransactionID");
```

After you have defined the column name this way you don't need to define it in the Migration code anymore.

The `name` parameter in the Migration class you are using influences the DDL script that is sent to the database but does not tell the EF model metadata that the column has another name.

Honestly I don't know any use case the `name` parameter in the Migration code might be good for.

**Edit**

I've tested that it works with the following example:

- I use your class:

  ```
  public class Transaction
  {
      public long Id { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- And this context where I define the column name with Fluent API:

  ```
  public class MyContext : DbContext
  {
      public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }

      protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
          modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>()
              .ToTable("dtlTransactions");

          modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>()
              .Property(t => t.Id)
              .HasColumnName("intTransactionID");
      }
  }
  ```
- Then I run `enable-migrations` and `add-migration InitialSchema` on the package manager console.
- I get this `DbMigration` class then:

  ```
  public partial class InitialSchema : DbMigration
  {
      public override void Up()
      {
          CreateTable(
              "dbo.dtlTransactions",
              c => new
                {
                    intTransactionID = c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true),
                })
              .PrimaryKey(t => t.intTransactionID);
      }

      public override void Down()
      {
          DropTable("dbo.dtlTransactions");
      }
  }
  ```
- Then I call `update-database -script` on the package manager console and get this DDL script for the table - which is the correct and expected script:

  ```sql
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dtlTransactions] (
      [intTransactionID] [bigint] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.dtlTransactions] PRIMARY KEY ([intTransactionID])
  )
  ```

Comment: Unfortunately doing that means that my model isn't POCO anymore. I don't like adding those attributes to my model, as it closely couples it to EF. Also, the name parameter doesn't influence the DDL script at all, as seen in my post.

Comment: Oh, I am actually using the Fluent API to map my entities. The mapping isn't the issue here. It's the DDL that gets generated that is wrong.

Comment: @ErnstKuschke: Is the DDL still wrong if you remove the `name: "intTransactionID"` from the Migration code?

Comment: If I remove that, the DDL doesn't know that I want my column to be named that.

Comment: @Slaume the PrimaryKey method actually accepts an optional 'name' parameter, but it doesn't seem to be used when generating the DDL. What I want is for the DDL to be created as follows:

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dtlTransactions] (
[intTransactionID] [bigint] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
--...other cols
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.dtlTransactions] PRIMARY KEY ([intTransactionID])

Comment: @ErnstKuschke: As said in my answer above you should name the column using `.HasColumnName("intTransactionID");` with Fluent API. That was the point of my answer. It should generate the correct DDL without specifying the column name in the migration code.

Comment: @Slaume Thanks for your suggestions. Since I want to use migrations, your solution doesn't help. It seems that there are indeed a few bugs in the migrations API.

Comment: The mapping of entities (whether with fluent API or with attributes directly) doesn't impact migrations whatsoever.

Comment: @ErnstKuschke: I've tested your example and my Fluent mapping in a console app to prove that it works, see my Edit section above. I don't understand where you have the idea from that entity mapping "*doesn't impact migrations*". "Mapping" means building a map between entity properties and table columns. If migrations would ignore this map it would be rather pointless.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is indeed a bug in the EF Migrations API, as confirmed over here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3868f5e7-144a-4212-9eb7-80a3b1e32fc2/entity-framework-migrations-primarykey#3868f5e7-144a-4212-9eb7-80a3b1e32fc2

Comment: The guy who answered there isn't a member of the EF developer team and I would not consider what he writes as a "confirmation", more as an opinion. Moreover he proposes the same solution as I did. I wouldn't call it a "workaround" because the mapping in the model metadata (with annotations or Fluent API) is essential so that EF can create SQL statements with the correct column names. You can't define this mapping with Migrations and it isn't its purpose. The purpose is to update a database schema and the migration doesn't know how to map this schema to the model classes.

Comment: @Slauma you don't seem to understand the issue. The solution he or you proposed weren't solutions. My classes *are* mapped, as you both suggested. The bug is *not* in the mapping, but in the Migrations, which ignore any custom name you give columns. This makes Migrations useless in EF.

Comment: Say, you have a class and add a property `Remark` to it and you call `.HasColumnName("X")` with Fluent API because you want that the column in the table is named "X" instead of `Remark`. You do this because when you run a query with `Where(a => a.Remark == "SomeText")` you tell EF that it must be translated into a SQL `WHERE X = N'SomeText'` (note: **X**, not **Remark**). Then you call `add-migration` and a migration is created that will add a column called "X" to the table (**not "Remark"**). **Why would you want to rename this column in this migration class into "Y"?**

Comment: Even if that would work (and it apparently doesn't completely work using the `name` parameter) the only result you will have is that your query with  `Where(a => a.Remark == "SomeText")` won't work anymore because the SQL query is still `WHERE X = N'SomeText'` (since `"X"` is the mapping in the model metadata), but now there isn't a column "X", but "Y" instead. Keep in mind that the migration is just a convenient replacement for opening SQL Server Management Studio and adding a column "X" manually to the table. You wouldn't call this column "Y" after you have defined "X" in your mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I tested using both mapping options (fluent and attributes). In both cases, when generating a migration using Add-Migration, any custom mappings are completely ignored.

The mappings work, but the migrations are not. This means that migrations are not usable when using EF as your ORM.

One workaround is to craft your migrations by hand, and instead of using the ***TableBuilder***, use the ***DbMigration*** methods:

Instead of

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.dtlTransactions",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true, name: "intTransactionID"),
            //...more cols
        })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id, name: "intTransactionID");
```

you can use:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.dtlTransactions",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true, name: "intTransactionID"),
            //...more cols
        });
AddPrimaryKey("dbo.dtlTransactions", "intTransactionId");
```

The same goes for TableBuilder.Index() - rather use CreateIndex() instead.

Comment: "*I tested using both mapping options (fluent and attributes). In both cases, when generating a migration using Add-Migration, any custom mappings are completely ignored.*" In other words you did exactly the same like I did in the Edit section in my answer and you don't get the result that I had??? Well, this is something you can *really* report as a bug if you can provide a reproducable sample.